# Dictionary for aggregation

Tags: c#, dictionary, counting

For aggregating the number of occurences of some certain values, I'm using a `dictionary<valueName:string, counter:int>`, I don't know the values exactly.
So I've written a method `SetOrIncrement`, which supposedly is used like

```
myDictionary.SetOrIncrement(name, 1);
```

However, there VisualStudio grumbls

> "Dictionary does not contain a definition for
>   'SetOrIncrement' and no extension method 'SetOrIncrement' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'Dictionary could be found."

Could anyone tell me what is the reason?

Here's the `SetAndIncrement` method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static int SetOrIncrement<TKey, int>(this Dictionary<TKey, int> dict, TKey key, int set) {
        int value;
        if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out value)) {
           dict.Add(key, set);
           return set;
        }
        dict[key] = ++value;
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you included the namespace for your extentionmethod, in the code where you are trying to use the extentionmethod?

Comment: No, but the class which is using the extensionmethod is in the same namespace.
`namespace test { class user { ... } public static class ExtensionMethods { ... } }`

Comment: Out of interest if the dictionary key already exists do you really mean it to ignore the value of set and still increment the value by one of do you mean it to do a `+=set`? It seems strange to ignore the parameter in some situations...

Comment: Yes, I'm sure of that, the dictionary's value is to be used as a counter. Actually, the set parameter could be left out since the counter always starts at 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your extension method compile correctly? When I try to compile it I get: "Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type".

The reason is that in this line:

```
public static int SetOrIncrement<TKey, int>(this Dictionary<TKey, int> dict, TKey key, int set) {
```

the `int` in the generic parameters for the method is not valid. Instead this should work:

```
public static int SetOrIncrement<TKey>(this Dictionary<TKey, int> dict, TKey key, int set) {
```

The reason being that `TKey` is the only type that varies. The int is always the same so isn't a generic parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void Main()
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    dict.SetOrIncrement("qwe", 1);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static int SetOrIncrement<TKey>(this Dictionary<TKey, int> dict, TKey key, int set)
    {
        int value;
        if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out value)) {
           dict.Add(key, set);
           return set;
        }
        dict[key] = ++value;
        return value;
    }
}
```